# How to remove MSSQL decimal declaration from QuerySet list?

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have a sorting algorithm that orders a list with parents and their children. Here is a working example: [Tutorials Point Coding Ground](http://tpcg.io/VBkGBK).

This working example, however, has a predefined "cleaned" list. The only difference however with this predefined list is that I have removed the "Decimal Declarations" (or whatever they are called) from the list. Here is an example of both dirty and clean lists.

**Dirty list:**

```
item_list = [
    {...},
    {'qmaQuoteAssemblyID': 0, 'qmaLevel': Decimal('1'), 'qmaParentAssemblyID': 0, 'qmaPartShortDescription': '12U x 600 x 650 Professional Rack', 'qmaPartID': 'RACK S9', 'qmaQuantityPerParent': Decimal('1.00000')},
    {...}]
```

**Clean List:**

```
item_list = [
    {...},
    {'qmaQuoteAssemblyID': 0, 'qmaLevel': 1, 'qmaParentAssemblyID': 0, 'qmaPartShortDescription': '12U x 600 x 650 Professional Rack', 'qmaPartID': 'RACK S9', 'qmaQuantityPerParent': 1.00000},
    {...}]
```

As you can see from both the examples that the *dirty list* has `Decimal('somevalue')` surrounding it's DecimalField value. However with the clean list it has that removed allowing it to go through the algorithm without a problem.

When I run the *dirty list* through the algorithm I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined
```

And within my Django project the list is simply considered empty.

This makes sense because Decimal isn't defined. But my environemnt seems to be treating `Decimal('somevalue')` as a method/function instead of it's raw decimal value.
I believe this "junk" is added around the value either from my MSSQL database or some other MSSQL → Django programs I have running parallel with my Django project.

I currently create the list like so:

```
con1 = Q(qmaQuoteID=quote_id)
con2 = Q(qmaQuoteLineID=quote_line_id)
query = QuoteAssemblies.objects.filter(con1 & con2
                              ).order_by('qmaQuoteAssemblyID'
                              ).values('qmaQuoteAssemblyID', 'qmaParentAssemblyID', 'qmaLevel', 'qmaPartID', 'qmaPartShortDescription', 'qmaQuantityPerParent')
item_list = list(query)
```

Is there a way to clean the list to remove the `Decimal('somevalue')` from the value so it goes through my algorithm correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this was the best way to deal with `Decimal('X')` being reprieved as a method/function. I simply declared `Decimal` as a class and made sure python only sees it as a value and in essence disregard the junk around it:

```
class Decimal:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        def value(self):
            print(self.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'Decimal' is not defined
```

just

```
from decmal import Decimal
```

if still does not work out and want to convert decimal to int or string,

```
for item in item_list:
    item['qmaLevel'] = int(item['qmaLevel'])
    # item['qmaLevel'] = str(item['qmaLevel'])
```

Comment: This was my original thinking however the actual value of both `qmaLevel` and `qmaQuantityPerParent` = `Decimal('somevalue')` so python is reading it as a method/function. Converting it to an int wont work because the text with the value will cause problem and converting it to string means I can't to calculations to the values later down the track within my project. So I am looking to remove everything besides the value of said fields. Also the values need to remain decimals because there are a few values which are decimals and an Int wont work.